# To find the total distance between two points A and B with just speed of train and difference in distance between two trains?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Two trains approach each other at 25 km/hr and 30 km/hr respectively from two points A and B. Second Train travels 20 km more than first. What is the distance between A and B ?

My approach:

Since $Distance = Speed \cdot Time$
[I just added the time it took to cover the distance taken by the Second train($30$ km/hr) to cover $20$ km to the First train($25$ km/hr) to get distance as constant]

(First Train)

For $20$ km at $25$ km/hr, the time taken would be

time $= \frac{20}{25} = \frac45$

> So First train taken would take $4/5$ time more to cover the distance $d$

$d = 25 \cdot (t + 4/5 )$   ---> (1)

$d = 30 \cdot t$          ---> (2)

Now since distance is constant and speed is inversely proportional to time,

Ratio of speeds $=  \frac{25}{30} = \frac56$

Ratio of times $ =  \frac{t+4/5}{t} = \frac{\frac{5t+4}{5}}{t} = \frac{5t+4}{5t}$

So

$\frac56= \frac{5t+4}{5t}$

Since it is inversely proportional

$5(5t+4)=6(5t)$

$25t+20=30t$

$25t-30t=-20$

$-5t=-20$

$t= 4$

So applying $t=4$ in (2) 
$d=30 \cdot 4 = 120$ km but its wrong

The correct answer is $220$ km

I don't understand! help

Comment: I don't know what $d$ and $t$ are in your work.  However, if $d$ is the length $AB$, then the two trains did not cover the whole length $d$ when they met.

Comment: d= distance between point A and B ,                                                                                   t =  time taken to cover the distance A and B     , the question is not about where they meet but the distance between A and B.

Comment: Of course, it's not about where the trains met, but you can't assume that, when they met, each train had traveled the whole distance $d$.  That's what you did in your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think best way to describe all the data is in a table like this

$\begin{array}{cccc}
 & \text{V} & \text{T} & \text{D}\\
\text{Train 1} & 25\,\left[\frac{km}{h}\right]\\
\text{Train 2} & 30\,\left[\frac{km}{h}\right]
\end{array}$

Denote the distance the first train traveled until the meeting
by $x$. Therefore the second train traveled $x+20$. Lets add this
to the table:

$\begin{array}{cccc}
 & \text{V} & \text{T} & \text{D}\\
\text{Train 1} & 25\,\left[\frac{km}{h}\right] &  & x\,[km]\\
\text{Train 2} & 30\,\left[\frac{km}{h}\right] &  & x+20\,[km]
\end{array}$

Now we can complete our table using that $T=\frac{D}{V}$

$\begin{array}{cccc}
 & \text{V} & \text{T} & \text{D}\\
\text{Train 1} & 25\,\left[\frac{km}{h}\right] & \frac{25}{x}\,\left[h\right] & x\,[km]\\
\text{Train 2} & 30\,\left[\frac{km}{h}\right] & \frac{30}{x+20}\,\left[h\right] & x+20\,[km]
\end{array}$

Assuming both trains left both points at the same time we get that
$T_{1}=T_{2}$ where $T_{1},T_{2}$ is the time travel for each train
until the meeting. So
$$
\frac{25}{x}=\frac{30}{x+20}\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad x=100\,\left[km\right]
$$
 Therefore the distance between $A$ and $B$ is $D_{1}+D_{2}$ where $D_{1},D_{2}$
is the distance each train traveled untill the meeting. So the distance
is
$$
\left(100\right)+\left(100+20\right)=220\,\left[km\right]
$$

Comment: why D1+ D2 ? you found x =120km ? I don't understand that.

Comment: @AbsoluteIdiot $D_1$  is the distance between point $A$ and the meeting point, this is the distance Train 1 traveled. $D_2$ is the distance between point $B$ and the meeting point, this is the distance Train 2 traveled. So the distance between $A$ and $B$ is just $D_1 + D_2$ (Assuming all three points $A,B$ and the meeting point are on a straight line)

Comment: @AbsoluteIdiot And $x=100\,\left[km\right]$ not $120\,\left[km\right]$

Comment: Can you provide rough sketch that shows points A,B,D1,D2,(20km),x in a line  if possible ? I am unable to visualize what's going on

Comment: @AbsoluteIdiot $D_1$ and $D_2$ are not points but DISTANCEs between points. Draw a line and denote both ends by $A$ and $B$. Then draw a point somewhere in the middle of the line - this is the meeting point. What are the distances of each of the segments?

Comment: ok i understood A,B,D1,D2. What about x , 20 km ? where are they on the line ?

Comment: @AbsoluteIdiot The distance between $A$ and the meeting point is $D_1=x$, that is the distance Train 1 traveled, and the distance between $B$ and the meeting point is $D_2=x+20$, that is the distance Train 2 traveled.

Comment: ok. i got it now. so you are saying first train meets  second train 100km and second train meets first train at 120 km. So total distance =100+120=220 km .  So in my first given solution all i had to do was to substitute t=4 in first equation and second equation, and add them. Am i correct.

Comment: What you can conclude is that the meeting point of both trains is $100km$ far from point $A$ and is $120km$ far from point $B$. And as for your solution i'm sorry but it's not very clear to me what you did there.

Comment: What i did was, since second train(30km/hr) covers 20 km more distance than first train. I calculated the time taken for the first train(25km/hr) to cover 20 km and added that time to the first train. So it covers 20 more distance. so i don't need to write distance + 20 in the equation.

Comment: @AbsoluteIdiot Both trains traveled the same time

Comment: yes, thats why i kept time variable (t) constant in my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Let them meet after $x$ hours.  We know that $25x+20=30x$, hence $x=4$. So one train travelled $25\cdot4$ km, the other $30\cdot4$ km, in total $220$ km.

Comment: I never could have thought of 25x+20=30x. Thanks.

Comment: @AbsoluteIdiot You’re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Let the unit of distance be *kilometers*, and let the unit of time be *hours*.  In the calculations below, all units are omitted. Since the problem statement is not clear, I am assuming that the trains simultaneously left from the endpoints ($A$ and $B$) and traveled towards one another.

Write $L$ for the total distance $AB$.  If $u$ and $v$ are the speeds of the first train and the second train, respectively, then we have
$$\frac{\,\,\frac{L-d}{2}\,\,}{u}=\frac{\,\,\frac{L+d}{2}\,\,}{v}\,,$$
where $d$ is the difference between the traversed distances of the two trains due to their different speeds (assuming that $u<v$).  From the above equation,
$$L=\left(\frac{v+u}{v-u}\right)d\,.$$
For $u=25$, $v=30$, and $d=20$, we get
$$L=\left(\frac{55}{5}\right)(20)=220\,.$$

Comment: Is it possible to solve it without using the above formula ?

Comment: Maybe, but why don't you work that out on your own, since I already pointed out the flaw in your work?

Comment: I am not sure,  so the equation would become like (First Train) d - 20= 25 * t - ->(1)  (Second Train) d + 20 = 30 * t -- > (2). Am i right ?

Comment: What is $t$?  The time the trains met?  If so, the first train did not travel the distance $d-20$ when it met the second train.  Likewise, $d+20$ is not the distance the second train traveled when it met the first train.

Comment: t is time . Distance(D) = Speed(s) x Time(t)

Comment: What time?  The amount of time I make my coffee?  The amount of time the first train needs to travel the whole $AB$?  The amount of time the second train needs to travel the whole $AB$?  The amount of time the trains spend passing one another?

Comment: https://dontmemorise.com/course/view.php?id=114      [time,speed and distance] [variation]. The following website told me that method.

Comment: I know your problem.  You don't know what your variables mean.  When you don't clearly define what they are, you will end up with confusion.

Answer (score 0):

$Distance = velocity\times time$.

For train 1; $v_1 = 25$.  For train 2; $v_2 =30$.  They both travel for the same amount of time;  $t_1=t_2 = t$.  And train 2 travels $20$ km more so $d_2 = d_1+20$.

So $d_1 = 25*t$ and $d_2 = 30*t$.

How far apart are they?  $D = d_1 +d_2$.

So:

1) $d_1 = 25t$

2) $d_2 = 30t$

3) $d_2 = d_1 + 5$ or $30t = 25t + 20$

4) $D = d_1 + d_2$  or $D = 25t +30t$ or $D= 25t + 25t + 20$

Four linear equations four unknowns   Just do them.

=====

Alternatively.  The difference in speed is $5 kph$.   The difference in distance is $20 k$.  So that time is $4$ hours.

(Note:  $\Delta d = d_2 - d_1$ and $\Delta v = v_2 - v_1$ so $\Delta d = d_2 - d_1 = v_2*t - v_1*t = (v_2-v_1)*t = \Delta v *t$ so just as $t = \frac {d_i}{v_i}$ we have $t =\frac {\Delta d}{\Delta v}$)

And the sum of the speed is $55 kph$ so the sum of the distances is $55*t = 55*4 = 220$.

(Note:  $\Sigma d = d_2 + d_1$ and $\Sigma v = v_2 + v_1$ so $\Sigma d = d_2 + d_1 = v_2*t + v_1*t = (v_2+v_1)*t = \Sigma v *t$ so just as $t = \frac {d_i}{v_i}$ we have $t = \frac{\Sigma d}{\Sigma v}$)